# What is the difference between .prototype and this. in defining methods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

These two examples aren't making any difference. But I just want to know what is the use of **object.prototype** property. And tell me which is one is the standard procedure in Object Oriented Programming in Javascript. Any illustration would be nice.

```
var Person = function(){

  this.name = "John Doe"

}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){

  console.log( "Hi, I'm "+this.name );
}

var John = new Person();

John.sayHello();
```

and here is another example without **object.prototype** property

```
var Person = function(){

  this.name = "John Doe";

  this.sayHello = function(){

    console.log( "Hi, I'm "+this.name );

  }

}

var John = new Person();

John.sayHello();
```

Comment: Without prototype a new function is created for every instance. Using prototype is better, there is only one function (method) delegated to all instances.

Comment: Properties should be in the class and methods should reside in prototype.

Comment: can you illustrate ? any simple example maybe?